# VSFTPD - 500 OOPS - missing value in config file : the presence of éthe "-R" option, so there is a strong case for enabling it

Tags: vsftpd

I've been having trouble getting Vsftpd to work. I can't seem to find an answer as to what this error means not and the missing value is?

What and where is the "-R" option supposed to be at ?

Here is my vsftpd.conf config, just in case :

```
listen=YES
listen_ipv6=NO
anonymous_enable=NO
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
chroot_local_user=NO
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd

rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.key
ssl_enable=YES
ssltlsv1_2=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO
allow_anon_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
require_ssl_reuse=NO
pasv_min_port=40000
pasv_max_port=50000
debug_ssl=YES
```

Has anybody ever been confronted by this ?

Comment: From where do you you receive this message? when stating the service? when executing a client ftp command? The only guess I can make is that it relates to the `ls_recurse_enable` option.

Comment: Oh. My. God. 

I checked that option, and there was an extra space in the comment line right above it............... 

I can't believe this .. thank you, @steeldriver.

Comment: OK so is what you show above your **complete** /etc/vsftpd.conf file, or did you omit some lines? The error you show suggests that a line was erroneously uncommented.

Comment: No, it wasn't the complete /etc/vsftpd.conf file : I didn't share the commented out lines. 

The error stated that the missing value was basically an extra space before the "#" above the `ls_recurse_enable` option.

Answer (score -1):

There was an extra space in the comment area, before the option.

```
 *EXTRA SPACE HERE* # the presence of the "-R" option, so there is a strong case for enabling it.
ls_recurse_enable=YES
```

Complete noob. Sorry, all.